# How to save multiple SELECT output of the sql query (or stored procedure) into separate dataframe (list of dataframes) using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, pyodbc

I have a sql query that returns two outputs (two select statements)
I need to save each output into pandas dataframe

```
SELECT 
'Brian' as EmpName, 1 as EmpNum
UNION ALL SELECT 'Tom' as EmpName, 2 as EmpNum

SELECT 'Los Angeles' as EmpCity, 'CA' as EmpState
UNION ALL SELECT 'Salt Lake City' as EmpCity, 'UT' as EmpState
```

So I am trying something like this in python:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect('my connection string')

SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(
'''
SELECT
'Brian' as EmpName, 1 as EmpNum
UNION ALL SELECT 'Tom' as EmpName, 2 as EmpNum

SELECT 
'Los Angeles' as EmpCity, 'CA' as EmpState
UNION ALL SELECT 'Salt Lake City' as EmpCity, 'UT' as EmpState, conn)

# here I want to iterate over outputs and save result into a list
df_list = []
for i in SQL_Query:
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query))
print(df_list)
```

but it doesnt give me correct result:

[image]

Comment: do it step by steps , you can run two sql query with one read_sql_querycall

Comment: Thanks, but I have a stored procedure that returns two select outputs